# Get the AccessToken inside the ProfileService in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

i have implemented the profileService for identity server 4 to add custom claims that i want. The idea is, before the claims are added to the token, i'm calling another .net api inside the `public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)` method. I'm making a `httpclient.getAsync("url/getInfo")` to get some info that i want to add later in the claims. `GetInfo` api endpoint have `[Authorize]` so i need the `Bearer {TOKEN}` in the header when i'm making the call. How can i get the Token inside ProfileService or how can i secure my request to the `/getInfo` endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I secure the route with CORS. I'm allowing to have calls only from the identity server:
In API's startup file:

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowIdentityServer", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["IdentityServer"])
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

And at the API's endpoint :

```
[EnableCors("AllowIdentityServer")]
```